# Opportunity Object - Price Book Lookup is always blank

Tags: opportunity, quote, pricebook, sales

When an opportunity has a new quote created, and a product (quote line item) is added to that quote, there is a dialog box that pops up and asks you to select a price book:

[image]

After selecting this price book, I was assuming that it would save this information to one of the objects... whether it be the Quote itself or the parent opportunity.

[image]

What I am finding is in BOTH instances, the lookup field is simply blank. Why is this?

I'm really scratching my head wondering what the point of the first dialog box is, if it doesn't ever save that information anywhere accessible to a system admin? Maybe I am just looking in the wrong place. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: and the quote line item was saved before you checked the Pricebook2Id field?

Comment: @cropredy Yes it shows up in the Quote Line Items Related List under the parent quote but the Pricebook2Id field is blank. I can manually add one, but I'm unsure why it is not automatically assigning that lookup value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately I believe that my issue is related to this:

https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000qQ52sAAC/price-book-lookup-field-on-quote-does-not-auto-populate-from-opportunity

It is a bug from 2017 with no resolution to this day except a work around of "Creating a Price Rule"

Comment: N.B. that article applies to OOTB Quote, not CPQ

Comment: @cropredy I believe that my org is actually not using CPQ and I mistakenly tagged this post as CPQ. I assumed that using the 'price book' objects was a direct feature of CPQ but or org does not have that package installed. With that being said , this issue directly applies to me and it is why I am having the problem. 

Unless you have any idea why else this may be happening I am going to say this issue is exactly what I am experiencing.

Comment: so - when creating the Quote from Opportunity; use a Flow to set the Quote.Pricebook2Id field

Comment: @cropredy What you are suggesting is a different work around. In that situation I have to know what price book was selected by the user when they add a product to the quote. That is seemingly impossible, so I have found a different way to handle this.

Comment: The quotes never get their pricebook from the opportunity. That is my whole point and reason I created this problem.

Comment: apologies -- a common usage model is that products are added to Opportunities and then a quote is created, using the opportunity Products to seed the quote products. IN this model, the Opportunity already has a pricebook2Id